# Project Euler #8 Python, I don't see what's wrong with the code

Tags: python

I started coding a month ago on Python and so far i've done the other 7 Euler problems but have been stuck on this one for a week now, here's the problem statement:

"The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?"

and here's the code i've written so far:

```
num = '\
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'

digit = str(num)


def find(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]

lst = find(digit, "0")

placeholder = "0"
series_sum = "0"

for element in lst:
    total = 1
    value = digit[int(placeholder):element]
    if len(value) == 13:
        for i in value:
            total *= int(i)
        if total > int(series_sum):
            series_sum = str(total)
    elif len(value) > 13:
        c = 0
        c2 = 13
        counter = len(value) - 13
        while counter > 0:
            for i in value[c:c2]:
                total *= int(i)
            if total > int(series_sum):
                series_sum = str(total)
            counter -= 1
            c += 1
            c2 += 1
    placeholder = str(element)

print series_sum
```

my approach here was to convert the number into a string, and make a list containing the index of the 0's, then iterating through the string and checking if there were at least 13 numbers between 0's, and do the math from there, but so far i've only managed to get it to work on the first 13 numbers, i think the bug might be in the part that says: `elif len(value) > 13:`.

also, any advice on which type of object (lists, strings, ints, etc.)to use for this kind of procedures and why is greatly appreciated.

edit: Solved it!, thanks a lot john, here's the code i used:

```
series_sum = 0

for i in range(len(num)):
    total = 1
    digits = num[i: i + 13]
    for i in digits:
        total *= int(i)
    if total > series_sum:
        series_sum = total

print series_sum
```

i now see that i wasn't being efficient at all, at least i know now

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the variable `digit` as `num` is already a string. To get all the chunks of 13 consecutive digits from `num` you can use a loop like this

```
for i in range(len(num)):
    digits = num[i: i + 13]
```

You'll get some shorter strings a the end, but they won't affect your quest to find the maximum product

Answer (score 0):

you can remove one for loop .... but for this imports are needed

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

total  = reduce(mul, map(int,digits), 1)



    with functools it is faster, than with for loop.
    test for 1000 runs 
    with for loop                    7.484771039336005    
    with functools                   6.376082365216808
```